# Java Regex applicable for two strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I need help with a Java Regex. I have a filename string which can have either of the below formats:

> number-yyyymmdd.text_1.xml

OR

> yyyymmdd.text_1.xml

I am able to get the <number> and <yyyymmdd> from the first format using below regex:

`"\\-(.*?)\\."` - gives me yyyymmdd

`"(.*?)\\-";` - gives me number

But with 2nd format (i.e. with <yyyymmdd>.text_1.xml) it throws error and doesn't return <yyyymmdd>. I need one regex for date format that will work with both strings.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex gives both number and date for format-1 and gives empty string and date for format-2

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String s1 = "number-20150606.text_1.xml";
    String s2 = "20150606.text_1.xml";

    Pattern p =Pattern.compile("(.*?)-?(\\d{8})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    while(m.find()) {

        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
    m = p.matcher(s2);
    while(m.find()) {

        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
number
20150606
          // Empty String here.
20150606
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was very helpful.